# doctrine:migrations:diff isn't working since I have updated to Symfony 6.3

Tags: symfony, console, doctrine

When I use the command

```
php bin/console doctrine:migrations:diff
```

I have this error

```
In get_Lock_Default_Store_TTEhGTService.php line 20:
                                                                                         
  Attempted to load class "StoreFactory" from namespace "Symfony\Component\Lock\Store".  
  Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?
```

[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jOyEL.png)

I have check lastest doctrine version and I am up to date, I have try to look in doctrine files but nothing...

Comment: You use the class StoreFactory without importing it per use statement or specifying the whole FQN. IDEs actually display something like this.

Answer (score 1):

Hello i found the solution, we just need to add  **composer require symfony/lock** and it's working again ;)

Answer (score 1):

In my case this was caused by [[RateLimiter] Move lock component to dev dependency](https://github.com/symfony/rate-limiter/commit/ac58c52423c5fabb55ec02009813fd5f1ea4d950) where **symfony/lock** was moved to dev but its configuration was still present in project.

There are two ways to resolve it:

- remove *config/packages/lock.yaml* (or equivalent config) and symfony/lock section in *.env* (one containing *LOCK_DSN* env variable)

or

- `composer require symfony/lock` directly

Comment: As the underlying issue is related to the container and a custom service removing a package is not really a valid solution in this case.

Comment: I'm not sure I understad. The issue was caused by symfony/rate-limiter removing symfony/lock dependency (moving it to dev), but configuration of symfony/lock was left behind. As a result, service in question (not a custom service, doctrine in symfony) tried to use symfony/lock even though it is not present, which is probably a bug. But solution is valid - either provide the symfony/lock, or remove its config so that service in question does not try to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like stale cache referring to a class that has been moved or deleted. Try removing the contents of `var/cache` directory. If it doesn't help, run `php bin/console -vv doctrine:migrations:diff` to get the stack trace.

Comment: Same problem after removing the cache

Comment: I have the same problem too, also after clearing the cache.

Comment: Please run `php bin/console -vv doctrine:migrations:diff`. The `-vv` part is important - this way you get the stack trace, and possibly more debugging details. Please paste the output in your question.